# How to fetch rows from associated hasMany model in Cake 3.0?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, has-many, belongs-to

```
//PagesTable.php
class PagesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->belongsTo('Books');
    }
}

//BooksTable.php
class BooksTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->hasMany('Pages');
    }
}
```

From the above two models, I want to retrieve pages that belong to a particular book in the `BooksController`.

After several hours of going through documentation, I somehow built this that is able to achieve what I want.

```
$pages = $this->Books->Pages->find()->where(['Pages.book_id' => $id]);
```

I have a feeling that I have not exploited cake here because it looks like I am building a custom query rather than just pulling the associated data. But as a beginner in cake 3.0 (with no experience in cake 2.x), this was the best I could do.

- Am I going the right way ?
- Isn't there a better way to find the pages of a book (rows of an associated hasMany model)?

Answer (score 0):

there is a simpler way check this:
in the controller

```
$maestro = $this->Maestro->get($id, [
'contain' => ['DetalleMaestro']]);
$this->set('maestro', $maestro);
```

this search in the db all the maestro records and the associated records detallemaestro
in the view

```
    <?php if (!empty($maestro->detalle)): ?>
    <h5><?= __('Fuentes de Informacion Asociadas') ?></h5>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th><?= __('Nombre 1') ?></th>
            <th><?= __('Nombre 2') ?></th>
            <th><?= __('Nombre 3') ?></th>
            <th><?= __('Nombre 4') ?></th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach ($maestro->detalle as $detalle): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= h($detalle->1) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($detalle->2) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($detalle->3) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($detalle->4) ?></td>
        </tr>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

this checks if Maestro has a association and display it